# Running BOINC on Debian

Tags: debian, distributed-computing, boinc

I run Debian unstable. I've installed boinc-client and boinc-manager packages. When i run boincmgr, it first says "Retrieving current status" and then "Unable to connect to the core client". http://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Installing_BOINC_on_Debian and http://wiki.debian.org/BOINC weren't helpful. I did the following command:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/boinc-client status
```

It returned:

```
Status of BOINC core client: running
```

How to make BOINC work on Debian?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your firewall allows BOINC GUI to connect to the BOINC deamon (port 31416)
2. Make sure that no other app is running at the same port.

How do you launch BOINC manager?

Comment: `lsof -i :31416` gives nothing and i don't use any firewall. i launch manager by running `boincmgr`.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a password in /etc/boinc-client/gui_rpc_auth.cfg and start your boincmgr with -p the_password_in_gui_rpc_auth.cfg.